# How to delete objects in Firebase using where clause?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have the following tree structure in Firebase, how can I go about where it should delete all the shifts where the `employeeid = (specified key)`?

```
"Shifts" : {
    "-KhJJMkElsuGRcgDgewb" : {
      "EndTime" : 1491973200,
      "ShiftId" : "-KhJJMkElsuGRcgDgewb",
      "StartTime" : 1491955200,
      "employeeid" : "UrjkB0QVJNTzSOHjDmxdyeecspG3"
    },
    "-KhJNv5itUJHhrxJlkLV" : {
      "EndTime" : 1491881400,
      "ShiftId" : "-KhJNv5itUJHhrxJlkLV",
      "StartTime" : 1491868800,
      "employeeid" : "SY6qNTB8EsbNoJ4qjQwX8goWmHE3"
    },
    "-KhJNwSHMn0Hfqtx81NJ" : {
      "EndTime" : 1492066800,
      "ShiftId" : "-KhJNwSHMn0Hfqtx81NJ",
      "StartTime" : 1492041600,
      "employeeid" : "UrjkB0QVJNTzSOHjDmxdyeecspG3"
    }
}

rootRef2 = firebase.database().ref().child("Shifts");
firebase.database().ref('Shifts')
      .orderByChild('employeeid')
      .equalTo(k)
      .limitToFirst(1)
      .once('value', snap => {
      rootRef2.child(k).remove();
      });
```

Comment: what have you tried? This is well documented in their docs and Stackoverflow isn't a tutorial service or free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code** that isn't working as expected

Comment: well i tried with the above code but it didnt work.. which is why i didnt bother posting it

Comment: so what is `k`? Does `once` return what you expect?

Comment: k is the employee id